# How to run a program without specifying the full path?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

How come when I type "rails", it won't work... but when I type "/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails" it will work? How do I bind it so that I don't have to type the full path everytime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a reference for script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191716/creating-a-reference-for-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to edit your `$PATH` environmental variable.

For example, in your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

Alternatively, you can use an alias, in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias rails=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails
```

Or you could even put the rails binary (or a symlink) to one of the directories listed in your `$PATH`.  To see those directories, type `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a soft link:

```
ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails /usr/local/bin
```

Then you can run `rails` directly.