# creating a reference for script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

I want to make the following kind of reference:

"ls" command, for example, is universally available in most *nix environments. User can type in from anywhere to execute the scripts.

So, I write script "x".  I want to make sure that from wherever the user type in x, the actual script "x" is referenced.

Thus, if I have script "x" stored in home/user/Desktop directory, I should not have to reference the script as follow:

```
home/user/Desktop/x
```

I should be able to do:

```
x
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to add the directory to your PATH.  E.g.

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/someDirectory"
```

You can add this line to `.bash_profile` to do it on startup.  However, you probably shouldn't add Desktop to the path because some browsers download to there by default (though it shouldn't be executable by default).

Answer (score 1):

You can also put your script in an existing directory that's already in your path such as `/usr/local/bin` or create a symlink there to your script's location.

```
cp /home/user/Desktop/x /usr/local/bin
```

or

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/x /usr/local/bin
```

or

```
ln -s /home/user/Desktop/x /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mean to be obnoxiously repetitive, but this is my first time answering a question, I can't reply to someone's already-good answer, and I think they are missing some important bits.

First, if you want to make sure everyone can access the script, you'll need to be sure everyone has execute permissions:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/script.sh
```

You'll also want to make sure it's in somewhere $PATH references (as the other answers mentioned):

```
echo $PATH # place the script in one of these directories
```

I would personally prefer /usr/local/bin, since that's considered *the* place for custom global scripts. Something the other answers didn't mention is that, if you do want to use a directory besides one in $PATH (say, /opt/myscriptfolder/) you'll want to add another PATH entry at the end of /etc/profile:

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/myscriptfolder/"
```

By putting this in the end of /etc/profile, all users will receive this modified PATH variable on their next login.